# SharePoint Permission to home page but not the entire site

Tags: 2010

I am using SharePoint 2010.  How do I give a user group permission to the home page without giving them permission to the entire site?

Answer (score 0):

if you go to your pages library and pick a specific page, you should be able to choose "Document Permissions".

You will have to "break" the permissions inheritance from the parent container by clicking "Stop Inheriting Permissions".

Your page has now its own set of permissions and you can add whoever you want without affecting other areas of the site, through the "Grant Permissions" icon.

You can grant any user or group the "View Only" permission, which will enable them so see that particular make, as long as there is a published and approved version of it.

Comment: In fact, you don't need to go to to pages library. Just when on home page select "Page" tab on ribbon and click "Page permissions". Then you can either break inheritance and add custom permissions or manage parent group.